# Bluetooth receiver is not working in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am working in an Android application to receive Bluetooth data from an Hardware Bluetooth device. I have seen all the posts of stack and also used sample app to design my code.
The problem is, my "Bluetooth receiver" is not working, whenever i send data from hardware device, it works for the first time but exactly 2nd time it always failed to receive the data notification.

```
public class BluetoothDataReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

ConfigClass.bluetoothDataReceive++;
if (ConfigClass.bluetoothDataReceive == 1) {
ConfigClass.showToast(context,
ConfigClass.MSG_RECEIVE_BLUETOOTH_DATA);

}else if (ConfigClass.bluetoothDataReceive ==2) {
ConfigClass.bluetoothDataReceive = 0;

}
}
}
```

Please help me out....I am struggling with this problem from a long time.

Comment: A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer active.

Comment: whats the solution for this then?

Comment: You need to use StickyBroadcastIntent. It stays around your service.

check this http://bit.ly/HNhPJa

Comment: I used this StickyBroadcastIntent, but getting same problem.
IntentFilter actionChanged=new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
Intent intent=this.registerReceiver(null, actionChanged);

Comment: I am in need to receive data periodically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the BroadcastReceiver.onReceive() runs in different thread than your UI. UI is not thread safe. Doing Toast() within it is a bad idea, and supposedly leads to unexpected results...